# How to disable the splashscreen of the rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, richfaces

When the rich:extendedDataTable return it's result, there a splashscreen (a little animated gif) displayed. 
And I'm searching for a way to removed it.

I noticed that in firebug

```
       .extdt-ss-vsbl { 
              background-image:url(/swf-rf-poc/spring/a4j/g/3_3_2.SR1org/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/loading.gif);
              border-bottom:1px solid #B6AD84;
              border-right:1px solid #B6AD84;
        }
```

and that in the pagesources

```
<div class="extdt-ss-vsbl" id="headerResultForm:searchResultSubview:searchResultsTable2:splashscreen"></div>
```

I've tried by overiding .extdt-ss-vsbl in the css of our apps but it didn't work. 
I tried to add .extdt-ss-vsbl in the xcss of our skin end leave it empty and it's didn't work either.

I noticed that in ExtendedDataTable.js there a method name showSplashScreen so I tried to overide it with jquery 
like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        JQuery.fn.showSplashScreen(function($) {
            //do nothing 
        }
        </script>
```

And it's didn't work either.

Is there a way to disable that splashscreen ?
I'm using jsf 1.2 and richface 3.3.3.Final

Comment: I don't see a splash screen in the demo? http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?tab=usage&cid=687162

Comment: It appear when you sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finaly you need to overide the value in the skin directly. 
so in the your skin you should have the extended-data-table.xcss defined and inside that files  define the following values :

```
<u:selector name=".extdt-ss-vsbl">
    <u:style name="background-image" value="none" />
</u:selector>
```

Hope it save a poor soul from searching countless hours.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you want to do this?

Comment: We added a splashscreen the we manage ourselve and we didn't wanted to have other splash to appear when it`s running. 
The rich:extendeddatatable seem to only splash when it`s receiving the data, but we wanted a splash that appear from the moment the user click a button.

Comment: Makes sense. I ended up writing a function that just made the splashscreen visible on button click. That unfortunately means hard-coding IDs everywhere, but it was a trade-off we were willing to make.

Comment: @Chris actually did you place the u:selector in the extended-data-table-xcss? is there anyway to make it seperate from that?

Comment: I unfortunately don't remember the specific but I think that what I did. I think if you don't do it that way you will have a double splashscreen, the one from the table and yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try to forcibly override the css class.

```
    .extdt-ss-vsbl { 
          background: none !important; 
          border: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's didn't work with that setting (in the css and the xcss in the apps skin)